# getAsObject not called

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, converters

What I am trying to do is that I am taking `timeMillis` property that stores time in millisecond(that I got my using `System.currentTimeMillis()`) and convert it to equivalent days,hours,mins and seconds after substracting it from the current time. The main problem is that whenever the converter `timeConverter` 
is called only `getAsString` function is invoked , `getAsObject` is not invoked.

Here is the part of my xhtml file which causing the converter to not run properly.

```
<c:forEach var="p" items="#{statusBean.statusList}">
    <h:form>
        <div class="status">
            <h:commandLink action="#{friendBean.gotoFriendProfile(p.email)}">
                <img src="../images/profilePicture/#{p.picture}" style="height: 29px; width: 29px; "/>
                <h:outputText value="#{p.statusBy}:"/>
            </h:commandLink>
            <h:outputText value="#{p.statusmsg}"/>
            <h:outputText value="#{p.timeMillis}">
                <f:converter converterId="timeConverter"/>
            </h:outputText>
            <br/>
            <c:forEach var="q" items="#{statusBean.commentList(p.statusId)}">
            <div class="barcomment">
                <br/>
                <h:commandLink action="#{friendBean.gotoFriendProfile(q.email)}">
                    <img src="../images/profilePicture/#{q.picture}" style="height: 29px; width: 29px; "/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{q.commentBy}:"/>
                </h:commandLink>
                <h:outputText value=" #{q.comment}"/>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
        <br/>
        <div class="comment">
            <p:inputText value="#{statusBean.comment.comment}" styleClass="box"  />
            <p:commandLink  value="Views" action="#{statusBean.update(p.statusId)}" ajax="false" styleClass="link"/>
        </div>
```

Here is the timeConverter class that I have written.

```
package com.converter;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;

public class TimeConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
        System.out.println("inside getAsObject");
        long time=Integer.parseInt(arg2);
        long currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        long eclapseTime=time-currentTime;
        long secs=eclapseTime/1000;
        long days=secs/(60*60*24);
        long hours=(secs%(60*60*24))/60*60;
        long mins=(secs%(60*60*24)%(60*60))/60;
        long secs2=(secs%(60*60*24)%(60*60)%(60));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(days).append("days").append(hours).append("hours").append(mins).append("mins").append(secs2).append("secs");
        String object1 = sb.toString();
        return object1;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) {
        System.out.println("inside getAsString");
        String value1 = value.toString();
        return value1;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why exactly is that a problem?

You're only using the converter here in an [`UIOutput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIOutput.html) component:

```
<h:outputText value="#{p.timeMillis}">
    <f:converter converterId="timeConverter"/>
</h:outputText>
```

The `getAsString()` is been called to convert the `Object` model value to a `String` which can be embedded in the generated HTML output (you know, you can't put Java objects plainly in a HTML string).

However, you're nowhere using it in an [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) component like `<h:inputText>`, so there is no means of a submitted `String` value which needs to be converted to the desired `Object` in the model, so the `getAsObject()` will obviously never be called.

Everything is working as designed. It look like that your concrete problem is that you should *actually* perform the job which you did in `getAsObject()` in the `getAsString()` instead.

I think that it would help if you give the methods a bit more sensible argument names:

```
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) throws ConverterException {
    // Write code here which converts the model value to display value.
    // This method will be used when generating HTML output.
}

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) throws ConverterException {
    // Write code here which converts the submitted value to model value.
    // This method will be used when processing submitted input values.
}
```